# chef test-kitchen configuration for Vagrant ssh connect timeout

Tags: unit-testing, chef-infra, vagrantfile, test-kitchen

My google-fu is failing me.  what do I need to put into my .kitchen.yml in order to get it to increase the config.vm.boot_timeout or number of attempts in my Vagrantfile.  My kitchen converge almost always hits:

```
  STDERR: Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
  Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
  the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.
```

After about another minute or so I can connect without issue.

I've tried many of what I thought it could be but none seem to be setting it to all of the following:

```
driver:
  name: vagrant
  vm.boot_timeout: 20
  vm:
    boot_timeout: 20

driver_config:
  require_chef_omnibus: true
  vm.boot_timeout: 20
  vm:
    boot_timeout: 20
```

What do I need to do to get this increased?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't supported directly, but you can copy the [default Vagrantfile.erb](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-vagrant/blob/master/templates/Vagrantfile.erb) and set

```
driver:
  name: vagrant
  vagrantfile_erb: path/to/your/Vagrantfile.erb
```

or possibly: (I forget which is needed)

```
driver:
  name: vagrant
  config:
    vagrantfile_erb: path/to/your/Vagrantfile.erb
```

Comment: I found this just in the last few minutes: https://gist.github.com/mattstratton/9095916 I'm testing it there now to see if it works.

Comment: boot_timeout isn't an option, as you can see in the default Vagrantfile template.

Comment: This didn't seem to fix it either.

Comment: found /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/kitchen-vagrant-0.15.0/templates/Vagrantfile.erb in my chefdk install.  I tried patching it directly into this file but it doesn't seem to be updating.

Comment: Do you mean the vagrantfile_erb option didn't work? If so, try under a config: subkey. I forget which cases request that.

Comment: updated the wrong one.  found erb that was being used and updated that one.

Answer (score 4):

I added:

```
driver:
  name: vagrant
  boot_timeout: 1200
```

It appears to work, the `boot_timout` is already present in Vagantfile.erb, maybe because of a newer version.